# GeoWebCache in GeoServer with PostGIS datastore not working

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geowebcache

I just install GeoServer 2.22.1 ->Add mapbox tile plugin->Create workspace->Create PostGIS datastore->add layer->Config Tile cache
Then I Seed cache layer from PostGIS data but have error by image below.
I also search in internet and no hope. How can I resolve?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question so that the error message is in the body as text (so it is legible on all devices and searchable by others).

Answer (score 0):

I finally find problem, this is a name of workspace, we must use lowcase for name in geoserver, It's working.
I change from mwg to MWG and MWG to mwg again.